# Appending a html element generated dynamically to an existing element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div element generated using javascript :

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);

iDiv.innerHTML = "I'm the first div";
```

Now I have a method which returns me the **"div"** element to the first created div element(`id="block"`). I am just receiving the output from a function(returnDiv()) and I dont have control to change anything inside the method . The output is as follows:

```
// returnDiv() returns me the following output which I am collecting in innerDiv variable

var innerDiv = <div style="width: 30px;"><div class="pBar" style="width: 100%;"><span title="100.00%" class="l r" style="background: red; left: 1px; width: 30px; box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);" rel="tooltip"></span><span title="0.00%" class=" r" style="background: rgb(255, 194, 0); left: 31px; width: 0px; box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);" rel="tooltip"></span></div></div>;

//document.createElement('div');

//innerDiv.className = 'block-2';

// The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.

iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
innerDiv.innerHTML = "I'm the inner div";
```

Here's the fiddle link :
https://jsfiddle.net/1988/5ff8dqbb/

The problem is inner Div is not visible , and the error says **"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
"** Since it is runtime I am not able make out whats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Better solution:**

```
var parser = new DOMParser()
var el = parser.parseFromString(innerDiv, "text/xml");
iDiv.appendChild(el.firstElementChild)
```

**Old solution:**

You can't append inerDiv to iDiv in this way. 
You can to this like that:
Change

```
`iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);`
```

to

```
`iDiv.innerHTML += innerDiv`
```